# Python: String iteration replace a space with a hyphen (or other character)

Tags: python, string, loops

I need to iterate through the string 'work_tip' and post each letter to a variable '`new_string`'. This is working fine. However I need to replace the white space with a hyphen or concatenate it completely. This is part of my studies so i can't use some of the other perhaps better syntax solutions available. I know it will be something really straightforward inserted into the below but I just can't figure out the additional step to take in finding the space and performing the additional function.

```
work_tip = "Good code is commented code"
new_string = ""

for letter in work_tip:
    new_string += letter
print(new_string)
```

> Desired output: Good-code-is-commented-code

Comment: Add `new_string.replace(' ', '-')` just before printing it

Comment: So you're asking how to check if a character is a space?

Answer (score 0):

```
work_tip = "Good code is commented code"
new_string = work_tip.replace(' ', '-')
print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for everyone's replies (this is my first Stack question :) ). As i suspected there is a really straight forward solution to this but for the 'replace' i'm not actually allowed to use that syntax yet as it's not been covered in the current module.

i did managed to get there in the end (and it's quite long winded because of the way we are expected to answer using only syntax we've covered. For anyone curious, please see below;

```
work_tip = "Good code is commented code"
new_string = ""
for letter in work_tip:
    if letter.isalpha():
        new_string = new_string + letter
    else:
        new_string = new_string + "-"

print(new_string)
```

quite long winded for what some covered in three lines but i'll get there some day.

Thanks again everyone!

Ed

Answer (score 0):

below is the solution. You can also try this.

```py
work_tip = "Good code is commented code"

new_string = " "

for letter in work_tip:

    if letter.find(" "):

        new_string = new_string + letter
    else:

        new_string = new_string + "-"

print(new_string)
```